# Selenium/Python: Loader not disappearing after using Selenium, even if I use EC.invisibility command

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, loader

```
def create_ep(self):
      a = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                        "//div[@class='btn btn-primary mr-1']")))
      self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", a)


There are two divs with that classname, one for the small animation(#2) I believe and another(#1) with opacity.
#1 <div class="position-absolute" style="inset: 0px; opacity: 0.7; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); backdrop-filter: blur(2px);"></div>
#2 <div class="position-absolute" style="top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);"><span aria-hidden="true" class="spinner-border text-primary"><!----></span></div>
```

There are 2 pages on the way to the Loader, the #3 is where the Loader gets stuck.

Page #1 is the log in one, I had no problem with that one (code not included for that one).

Page #2 is the homepage after I'm logged in, and then I use 'By.XPATH', I managed to click on that button which is taking me to the 3ed Page.

Page #3 is the problematic one since the Loader seems to be stuck, I tried using invisibility_of_element but I get a timeout, I also tried using the same 'element_to_be_clickable' without much success, for some odd reason I'm able to fill in the information in some of the fields even if I have the Loader running in the background.

I've been trying several methods that I found on Stackoverflow and the results were poor.
I also tried using Chrome and Firefox, both give the same result.

With both browsers, I get 'Process finished with exit code 0' and yet the Loader still appears.

[Loader animation printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yltju.png)

Comment: Managed to solve it with Refresh command for now.

Comment: Refresh stopped working, since the website I'm testing has a login, and I believe that the selenium refreshed without waiting for the page to fully load, I used time.sleep(5) for now it seems fine.